# Different Behaviors Dependent on Form Button Clicks?

Tags: php

So, I would like to tie different behaviors to the same button on a Zend PHP form.  Here is an example of the kind of code I have now:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $this->_helper->messenger->addSuccess('Are you sure you would like to delete this link? The link and all statistics tied to it will be permanently deleted if you take this option.');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this code seems to continue to display the messenger no matter how many times I click submit.  So, my questions are

1. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
2. What could I do if my desired behavior is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of the button according to the operation you want that to do. Like, by default set the value to 1, and when submitted once, dynamically set the value of the button to 2. Now depending on the value of the `$_POST['submit']` show alert or take action.

sample code :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['submit'] == 1) {

        //submitted first time
        $this->_helper->messenger->addSuccess('Are you sure you would like to delete this link? The link and all statistics tied to it will be permanently deleted if you take this option.');
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] == 2) {    
        // second time, so take action
        ...
    }
}
```